# Javascript Nested If Statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have searched everywhere, but still unable to answer the question. 
Essentially, what I need to do is a nested if statement.

Below is my code, but i'm getting the error message saying "SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'else', line 198", which is referencing the line after the alert!

```js
  if((z!=='#EANF#')){
      var signdec
  signdec =  "CODE:"
  signdec +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=TXT:*" + "\n"
  signdec +=  "TAG POS=R3 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*" + "\n"
  signdec +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:No<SP>i<SP>data<SP>found. EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"
   iimPlay(signdec);   
} 



   alert(iimGetExtract())
   else if((iimGetExtract()!=='#EANF#'));{
   iimPlay(sign)
   iimPlay(after)
  
}
    alert(iimGetExtract())
    else if((iimGetExtract()=='i'));{
    iimPlay(goback)
    iimPlay(goback)    
}



   else if((iimGetExtract()=='#EANF#')){
    iimPlay(goback)
    iimPlay(goback)
    
}


 else((z=='#EANF#'));{
 iimPlay(goback)
}
```

Any help appreciated, also If there is a way to shorten this, please let me know.

Comment: Random formatting, random semicolons, you're begging for bugs

Comment: Your `if-else` syntax is simply wrong. Read [the docs about `if-else` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) and try to correct it yourself.

Comment: Re your comment on a now-deleted answer: *"Thaks for the quick response. I have updated the question as it's still not working!"* That's now how SO works. You don't change the question to invalidate an answer. You can say "I've tried that but it didn't work," but you can't change the question so that it invalidates an answer.

Comment: There is no reason to double-up your parentheses. `if((z!=='#EANF#'))` is exactly the same as `i((z!=='#EANF#')`.

Comment: I suggest putting aside what you're currently working on and working through some basic JavaScript tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Between `if` and `else if` there cannot be any `alert`.
   Once you break the condition with an `alert`, it is essentially a new conditional statement, and conditional statement cannot start from `else if`.
2. Also, right after else if you cannot put a semicolon. It will end
   the statement there only (you are probably confusing python with
   javascript).

This is what an `if...else if...else` looks like:

```
if (someCondition) {
    somethingHere();
} else if (someOtherCondition) {
    somethingElseHere();
} else {
    yetAnotherThingHere();
}
```

Note where the semicolons are, and aren't. Note that there is nothing between the ending `}` of an `if` block and the `else`.

Or if you prefer (this is closer to the style in your question):

```
if (someCondition) {
    somethingHere();
}
else if (someOtherCondition) {
    somethingElseHere();
}
else {
    yetAnotherThingHere();
}
```

...as line breaks are unimportant.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, despite removing the alert.

Comment: @T-J-Crowder thanks for editing the answer to make it more informative.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible structure would be the [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement for continuing `if ... else if ... else if` scheme.

```
switch (true) {
    case z !== '#EANF#':
        signdec = "CODE:";
        signdec += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=TXT:*" + "\n";
        signdec += "TAG POS=R3 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*" + "\n";
        signdec += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:No<SP>i<SP>data<SP>found. EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
        iimPlay(signdec);
        alert(iimGetExtract()); // where ever this should happen
        break;
    case iimGetExtract() !== '#EANF#':
        iimPlay(sign);
        iimPlay(after);
        alert(iimGetExtract()); // where ever this should happen
        break;
    case iimGetExtract() == 'i':
        iimPlay(goback);
        iimPlay(goback);
        break;
    case iimGetExtract() == '#EANF#':
        iimPlay(goback);
        iimPlay(goback);
        break;
    case z == '#EANF#':
        iimPlay(goback);
        break;
}
```